# Random variable in an urn modell?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In an urn exist $N$ numbered marbles, you take them out $n$ times without returning. 
The random variable $X$ defines the smallest number drawn. Determine the value range and the distribution of $X$.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: I know that the definition of the distribution of the random variable is $P_X(A^*):=P(X^{-1}(A^*))$ in a probability space of $(\Omega,\sum,P)$ with the event space of $(\Omega^*,\sum^*) \forall A^*\in\sum^*$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The balls can be taken simultaneously. You have $\binom Nn$ different draws.

$X(\Omega)=\left\{1,2,\dots,N-n+1\right\}$. Saying $X=k$ means you have taken the ball $k$, and $n-1$ balls numbered over $k$. So for $k\in X(\Omega)$, 
$$P(X=k)=\frac{\binom{N-k}{n-1}}{\binom Nn}$$

Comment: much appreciated!